# WPF application throws "EnumConverter cannot convert from System.Boolean." exception in app.Run function

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application with MainView.xaml inside a MainWindow.xaml. When I launch the application, it throws an exception with the message mentioned in the title. When I try to debug it, I find out that it it thrown in this line:

```
 app.InitializeComponent()      
 app.Run()
```

in the Application.g.vb file, which is automatically generated. But since the exception only has this message, no inner exception, I have really limited information about what enum value it is trying to convert. Plus, it doesn't seem to (directly) relate to WPF components composition, because normally for those kind of problem the exception is thrown in the InitializeComponent() function call of each Window or UserControl. But that doesn't happen. My MainWindow and MainView were all composed correctly (of course I believe there is some error inside them, but I mean .NET doesn't find them). Could anyone point to me where to start debugging this problem?

Comment: Search for the EnumConverter in your XAML. If possible, post it in your question.

Comment: @ken2k  That also doesn't exist in my code. So I am guessing it is .NET trying to parse it. Of course I have many enum, so I just don't know where to start

Comment: If the code is not too long, you could consider posting it.

Comment: @ken2k thanks for your comment. But I don't even know which part to post. I have many xaml views, and the exception is thrown only at app.InitializeComponent, so I don't know where to start...

Comment: Turn on the Break on all exception feature in VC. Under Debug > Exceptions (Ctrl+Alt+E) and check the two checkbox in the row: Common Language Runtime exception. Maybe you can find some hint in which view the exception is comming from. Also check the inner exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be one of my converter is having this problem. Actually I have a generic boolean converter which convert true or false to give given TrueValue and FalseValue. But there was some error in the Convert function so it wouldn't actually convert the boolean to, this time a enum value, the given type.